# Query with multiple foreign keys to the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a MySQL query that will significantly optimize my Rails 3 application.

I have 2 tables that are primarily involved: segments and organizations

Table defs are:

**segments**

- name
- organization_id
- override_id
- default_id
- playlist_id
- position

**organizations**

- ancestry
- ancestry_depth

---

Think of segments as tracks in a playlist.  A track may be overridden, hence the override_id.  A track may also have a default, hence the default_id.  If a track has both an override or a default the override should take priority.  If this isn't already tricky enough, there is another wrinkle -- overrides have to consider the hierarchy of their associated organization.

---

### [Sample Data & Expected Results](http://media.10footwave.com/stackoverflow.html)

---

Here's my explanation of the expected result set row by row:

Row #1 - Override #1 with ID #9 is used because it overrides Segment #1 (as does Override #1 w/ID #5) but the organization associated with ID 9 has a lower ancestry depth (2) than the ancestry depth of the organization associated to segment ID #5, which is 3.

Row #2 - Override #2 with ID #6 is used because it overrides Segment #2 and there isn't another override available with the same organization that has a lower ancestry depth.

Row #3 - Default #2 is used because there are no overrides available for Segment #3.

Row #4 - Segment #4 is used because there are no overrides or default available.

---

I've made many attempts at a query that would give me these results and I'm nowhere close.  My latest attempt used a UNION which gave me interesting results because I could see the correct list of segments and the correct overrides appended to the bottom, however, it's far from what I described above.

I would greatly appreciate any help and/or direction.

Thank you!

Louis

Comment: What are the primary keys of these two tables and what are the foreign key relations? Also, please provide a small set of sample data and expected results.

Comment: I have built you a SQLFiddle => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dc68. I anyone that attempts this the best of luck, because you have built this structure terribly for what result set you want.

Comment: Hi, the primary key for each is just the id.  The segments table has the following foreign keys: organization_id to organizations table, override_id to segments table, and default_id to segments table.
Link to sample data and expected results: [link](http://media.10footwave.com/stackoverflow.html)

I understand the structure isn't optimal.  The override and default concepts were added much later.

Thanks again for your time.  Much appreciated!